# When creating a library in Android, the res folder is not created in the new module

Tags: android, android-library

When creating a new module to create a new library, a **res** folder is not created in the new module, but in the tutorials on the Internet, this folder is created automatically.
How do I fix this problem?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h66sA.png)

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you manage to fix it? If yes please share your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android studio then I suggest you to create activity instead of class